# Silverstripe 404 Error - for public and admin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I installed Silverstripe but get a 404 error for the website home page and admin panel. Can anyone advise how to fix this.

Thanks

I went through Silverstripe support docs and checked out some forums forums, but no luck so far.

Comment: Hi there,

There's not enough information here to provide any specific help - "I installed Silverstripe" doesn't tell us anything about your installation. Most likely this is a misconfigured apache setup (make sure your virtualhost points at the `public/` directory) but it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, so here is my answer.
One reason you can run into this problem is if your `.htaccess` file isn't being used correctly. This is because SilverStripe relies on the `.htaccess` file for routing and handling of file access.

If you are using Apache, then you probably don't have the `AllowOverride` directive in your Directory section configured correctly.

For Apache, the easiest solution is simply to set `AllowOverride` to `All`, like so:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mySite/public/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```